# Facebook analytics for a website or a page

Tags: facebook, analytics

A while ago I went on FB development site where I can input a URL (a website or a non-FB page). The tool will show me how many FB likes and the comments people wrote on FB regarding the site or page.

Can someone help me remember the URL of this tool?  If not, can someone show me a tool that can show this data?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is Domain Insights. Unfortunately, facebook stopped supporting these in 2016.  

**Facebook is no longer accepting new domains for Domain Insights, but if you have previously registered a domain, you can continue to use Domain Insights for that domain.**  

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains)

Comment: @Neil - So sad to hear.  I thnk that's the closest thing I've seen.  Thank.